# How to find conditional expectation $\mathbb E(X|X<M)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, self-learning, expectation

Consider a random variable $X$ following the so-called folded normal distribution. That is, $X$ has density function

$$
f_X(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi\tau}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\tau}}, x>0.
$$

> Question: Find $\mathbb E(X|X<M)$, where $M>0$ is a constant.

I do not know how to start this. Like what exactly does this thing mean. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: You want $X$ to be a positive random variable and $f_X(x) = 0$ for negative $x$ accordingly, I think.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think there is an explicit expression for this conditional expectation, because you would basically need an explicit expression for the so called error function (erf) which doesn't exist.

Comment: what is $M$ another random variable or just some value in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @thomas Yes, I added that in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @mjb4 $M>0$ is a constant. I added that in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @thomas What is error function? Could you give an example where similar thing can be found, please? Thanks.

Comment: "I do not know how to start this." This is explained in excruciating details on the stats.SE page you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the support of the folded normal is $[0;\infty)$ the conditional expectation is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X\mid X<m)
& = \int_0^\infty x f_X(x\mid X<m)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
& = \int_0^\infty x \frac{f_X(x)\mathbf 1_{[0;m]}(x)}{F_X(m)}\operatorname d x
\\[1ex]
& = \int_{0}^m x f_X(x)\operatorname d x \;\Big/\; \int_{0}^m f_X(x)\operatorname d x 
\\[1ex]
& { = \int_{0}^m x f_X(x)\operatorname d x \;\Big/\; \int_{0}^m \sqrt{{2}/{\pi\tau}\;}\;e^{-{x^2/2\tau}}\operatorname d x } 
\\[1ex]
& { = \int_{0}^m x f_X(x)\operatorname d x \;\Big/ \operatorname{erf}(m/\sqrt{2\tau}) }
\\[1ex] & \vdots
\end{align}$$

---

Where $\operatorname {erf}(\bullet)$ is the [Error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By Bayes' rule, we have $f_X(x|X<M) = \frac{f_X(x, X<M)}{F_X(M)}$. How did you get to the second line in your answer, please? In particular, how to understand $f_X(x, X<M)$, please?

Comment: @20824 The probability density of $X$ at point $x$ *and* $0\leq X\leq M$ is: $f_X(x)$ when $0\leq x\leq M$ and $0$ elsewhere.$$f_X(x)\mathbf 1_{[0; M]}(x) =\begin{cases}f_X(x) & : 0\leq x\leq M \\ 0 & : \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$This is analogous to $\mathsf P(K=k, 0\leq K\leq N) = \mathsf P(K=k)\mathbf 1_{[0;N]}(k)$

Comment: Doesn't your answer contradict what I found from http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96057/prove-mathbb-exx0-mathbb-ex-mathbb-px0 ???

Comment: Why do we have $\mathbb E (X|X<M) = \frac{\mathbb EX}{\mathbb P(X<M)}$, please? Thanks.

Comment: @20824 We don't.  Notice the upper bound on the numerator's integration.  We have $\mathsf E(X\mid X < M) = \mathsf E\big(X\;\mathbf 1_{[0;M)}(X)\big)\big/ \mathsf P(X < M)$ .